# samba default owner and file security mode

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04, samba

I shared a folder from Ubuntu 16.04 to my local network - so that another machine can see, edit files on that folders.

All good, except that if I copy a file from another machine (Win10) to that shared folder, the file permission is always like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 pac   pac     4096 Dec 15 09:59 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 pac   pac      4096 Dec 15 09:56 ../
-rwxr--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 505138 Dec 15 09:48 ap1.txt*
```

As seen with the last line, the default owner is `nobody:nogroup` and the permission is `-rwxr--r--` that means I can't edit the file from Ubuntu16 even that it's where the original shared folder locates.

Is there a way to fix this issue? such that I can seemlessly copy/edit files on that shared folder regardless of what machine I am on.

(p/s: currently I have to do `chown` and `chmod` manually for the file described above to be able to edit it from Ubuntu16.04 - but it's just so inconvenient).

Comment: got to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and add theses to the __[global]__ section: create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755, or to whatever value you may like. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @George thanks. I added the following to `[global]` section, yet the file I copied over from Windows10 to Ubutu16 still show the same permission as described above.

`
# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700
create mask = 0755

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700
directory mask = 0755
`

Comment: sorry not sure how to format that comment better